# Was the Levite a father to Micah? Was it the other way around?

Tags: judges

> Judges 17:10 “Stay with me,” Micah said to him, “and be my **father** and priest, and I will give you ten shekels of silver per year, a suit of clothes, and your provisions.”
> So the Levite went in 11 and agreed to stay with him, and the young man became like a **son** to Micah.

Who is the father? Who is the son?

Comment: "Av" אָ֣ב can also mean 'Instructor'. * You have found an excellent riddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title "father" is honorific and does not denote age nor biological connection.  The comments of Ellicott summarise this situation:

> (10) Be unto me a father and a priest.—The title “father” is here
> ecclesiastical, like “papa,” “pope,” &c, and this title was given to
> spiritual directors, as we find in several other passages in the Bible
> (2Kings 2:12; 2Kings 5:13; 2Kings 6:21; Isaiah 22:21, &c.). Micah knew
> enough of the law to be aware of the extreme irregularity of his
> conduct in making one of his own sons his priest.

The Cambridge commentary observes exactly the same thing:

> 10. father] A title of honour given to a priest Jdg 18:19, a counsellor Genesis 45:8, cf. [Apocr.] Esther 16:11, 1Ma 11:32, a
>     prophet 2 Kings 2:12; 2 Kings 6:21, a master 2 Kings 5:13, a king 1
>     Samuel 24:11.

Benson is very similar:

> Jdg 17:10. Be unto me a father — That is, a priest, a spiritual
> father, a teacher or instructer. He pretends reverence and submission
> to him; and what is wanting in his wages, he pays him in titles.

Matthew Poole adds some interesting detail:

> A father and a priest; for, a father; that is, a priest; a spiritual
> father, a teacher or instructor, for such are called fathers: see 2
> Kings 6:21 8:9 13:14 Isaiah 22:21. He pretends reverence and
> submission to him; and what is wanting in his wages he pays him in
> empty titles.

Thus, under the idiom and culture of ancient Israel, there was no problem in calling a young priest both "father": and "son" and Josh 17:10, 11 clearly shows.